# Crystal Reports: export datasource with report definition

Tags: crystal-reports, export, report, datasource

I am stepping into a new reporting environment and I don't have a lot of background info yet.  But my company utilizes a series of crystal reports.

I want to compare two reports that are identical except that they connect to different data sources.  I can click on both reports in the Crystal Reports viewer, go to Database > Set Database Location and I am able to see the data source.  If I do this for both reports in question, I can see that they both connect to different data sources, as expected.

However, when I export  the two Crystal Reports as text files and then compare them using Notepad++, I don't see the datasource / connection string in the report files, so when I do a compare, they are exactly the same.

If the exported text files are exactly the same, how does Crystal Reports Viewer know to point one report towards a prod data source and another report towards the dev data source?  It does not appear to be embedded in the exported metadata / report definition file.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The connection info is simply not part of the exported report definition text.
But, obviously, it is part of the report definition.

If you need to export more detailed report definition information, including connection properties, consider getting a documentation utility. Ken Hamady maintains a list of those [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#doc).

Comment: It is very odd that the "exported report definition" is different than the "actual report definition".  I didn't know that!  Thanks for the education.  I will see if one of the tools from your link might do the trick.  Thanks again.